# Remove all lines that start with a number using python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to remove all lines in a file that starts with numbers. I came up with that block of code below but it's not working.

```
output = open("/home/test1/Desktop/diff2.txt", "w")

with open("/home/test1/Desktop/diff.txt") as input:
    for line in input:
    if not line.lstrip().isdigit():
        output.write(line)
        print(line)

    input.close()
    output.close()
    exit();
```

It still ends up printing all lines that start with numbers in the output file

Comment: Can you supply an example of the file?

Comment: You have an indentation error in the snippet you posted for the contents of the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, i'll edit the question with it

Comment: I tried to copy and past the input and output files but it keeps putting them all in one line on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following script works fine on my quick test case:

```
output = open("test.out", "w")

with open("test.in") as input:
    for line in input:
        if not line.lstrip()[0].isdigit():
            output.write(line)
            print(line)

output.close()
```

With input:

```
1test
2test
hello
3test
world
4something
```

Gives output:

```
hello
world
```

Answer (score 1):

The `lstrip().isdigit()` doesn't check the first char in your line is a digit. You should take the first char (if the line has chars) and check `isdigit()` on that char:

```
if line == '' or not line[0].isdigit():
    output.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `is_digit` on the whole line, which will return `True` only if the line consists entirely of digits.

```
with open('input.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
  out.write(''.join(l for l in inp if l[0] not in '123456789'))
```